# Construye el arreglo “Num” con los números del 1 al 20 y filtra en una variable llamada “Datos” los números mayores a 14 para mostrarlos en consola

Tags: javascript

necesitó esta condiciones, pero no se como hacerlo.   Construye el arreglo “Num” con los números del 1 al 20 y filtra en una variable llamada “Datos” los números mayores a 14 para mostrarlos en consola.

Comment: Buenas, lorena, acá no se hacen las tareas de los demás, se resuelven problemas de programación, cosa que es diferente. Segun la pregunta eso si, debes crear un arreglo y filtrar eso datos para mostrarlos, cosa que no demoras mas de 10 minutos buscarlo en internet, por favor por un poco de esfuerzo en el estudio. Busca como crear un arreglo en JS, y luego busca como filtrar, lo cual se hace recorriendo el arreglo.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque falta demostración de búsqueda y esfuerzo para hacer el ejercicio.

Comment: Entiendo que debería poner un ejemplo de lo que intentó hasta el momento. Pero de todas formas la pregunta es muy clara y sencilla de responder. Con una simple respuesta el OP puede aprender cómo hacer lo que necesita

Comment: Por eso es que cometes un error al hacérsela entera...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Construye el arreglo “Num” con los números del 1 al 20

Para esta parte puedes escribir el [arreglo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) número por número:

```js
let Num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
console.log(Num);
```

O usar un bucle for:

```js
let Num = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
   Num.push(i);
}

console.log(Num);
```

> filtra en una variable llamada “Datos” los números mayores a 14 para mostrarlos en consola.

Para filtrar los número puedes hacer uso de la función [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let Num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
let Datos = Num.filter(num => num > 14);

console.log(Datos);
```

Comment: Buenas, te recomiendo que nunca le hagas la tarea a alguien más, por que solo aprenderá a copiar y pegar, al menos debe demostrar que lo ha intentado y poder corregir sus errores, pero nunca hacer la tarea entera.

Comment: Hola @Excorpion entiendo a lo que te refieres, siempre trato de no contestar este tipo de respuestas, pero de todas formas me pareció una pregunta simple y fácil de contestar. Por otro lado no sabes si OP va a copiar y pegar o aprender, me gustaría creer que a partir de esta respuesta va a tener un empujón para poder seguir aprendiendo

Comment: La pregunta terminará siendo cerrada por ese motivo, como dije, debe demostrar un mínimo de interés en lo que estudia, por que tu no sabes, si la respuesta que le estás dando, es una tarea, o una prueba... ahi el punto, no sabes que nivel tiene siquiera...

Comment: Si, como te digo, entiendo a lo que te refieres. Quizas me precipité en contestar, espero que pueda editarla. Saludos y gracias por el feedback

Comment: gracias por la explicación ya entendí como hacerlo, yo lo estaba haciendo al revés pero gracias a tu ayuda pude entender. Gracias Andres Gardiol

Comment: Me alegro @lorena que te haya sido de utilidad. Te recomiendo que en un futuro para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas, hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]. Por último, si resolvió tu problema marca la respuesta como aceptada.